# How to set property in app delegate for tabview controller

Tags: swift, tabs, navbar, appdelegate

I've read several of the suggested posts that were to help with this problem but could not find something for this particular issue.

I need to set a property on my controller, the book is saying to do so in the app delegate. In the previous assignment using a navbar, this worked:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Create an ItemStore to hold list of items
    let itemStore = ItemStore()
    // Access the ItemsViewController and set its item store
    let itemsController = window!.rootViewController as! ItemsViewController
    itemsController.itemStore = itemStore

    return true
}
```

However, creating a similar program I need to use tab bar but can't get it to work and keep running into the error stated above, on the let editcontroller = tabcontroller. - line

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Create an pindatabase
    let pinDataBase = PinDatabase()

    // Access the pairsViewController and set its database
    let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    // this edit controller line is where I am stuck
    let editController = tabController.tabBar as! EditViewController
    editController.pinDataBase = pinDataBase

    return true
}
```

The error is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The controller I'm trying to set the property on is not the root controller but the third tab if that helps.

Comment: What error? You did not post an error or point out the exact line causing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your attempt to cast the `UITabBar` to your `EditViewController`. You need to access the array of view controllers from the tab bar controller and access the one that is actually the `EditViewController`.

```
let editController = tabController.viewControllers[2] as! EditViewController
```

This will access the 3rd view controller and cast it as needed.